# How to use github api v3 to revert a pull request, or revert a commit? (NOT from github UI)

Tags: github-api

The problem has been described clear on title

I have read the document at : https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

NO code needed

I just want to know is that possible?  If yes, which API I should look into?  Or impossible for now, I will look for other solution path.

Comment: Looks like no one use github API to revert a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub provides [two APIs: a REST API and a GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/about-githubs-apis).

You're referring to the REST API, unfortunately this is one of the cases where there's a feature mismatch between the two. It not possible with GitHub REST API, but it is possible with [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql).

In GraphQL API you'd use [`revertPullRequest` mutation.](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#revertpullrequest)